# How do I correct the error that ylim needs finite values?

Tags: r, statistics, bupar

I keep getting a ylim value error and tried to correct it couple of times with no help. Can anyone help me?

Getting this error code: `Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values`

```
throughput_time_qcc <- qcc(log(ntp_casestats_mr$throughput_time), type = "xbar.one", 
                       labels = ntp_casestats_mr$case_id, plot = FALSE) 

plot(throughput_time_qcc, title = "X (individual measurements) chart for throughput time (hours)", 
 xlab = "Case ID", ylab = "log (throughput time)", digits = 2, )

process.capability(throughput_time_qcc, spec.limits = c(NA, log(100)), nsigmas=3, digits = 2)
```